# Outlook add-in authenticate with token to SharePoint

Tags: azure, sharepoint, outlook, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices

Using the new Outlook Add-in API I want to make some calls into SharePoint Online as the user and create a few items.
Everything is in O365 and the same tenant, so I'm logged in to Outlook with the same credentials as I use to login to SharePoint.

I can see `getUserIdentityTokenAsync` and `getCallbackTokenAsync`, but can I use that token to connect to SPO directly from JS?

From what I can see these tokens are for "third party apps" and EWS respectively.

Can I use either of these tokens to authenticate with an Azure AD application?  Which I know I can configure to allow access to SPO.

Ideally I'd rather not prompt the user to login again within my add-in.  Which I know I can do and am doing in an Office add-in, which doesn't have the getToken methods.

Thanks

Comment: I am working on same scenario. can you help me if you have an answer for this?